# Edit dict recursively in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a dict like this

```
{
  "library": [
    {
      "_type": "Host",
      "parameters": "JSON STRING",
      "superclassOf": [
        {
          "_type": "LinuxHost",
          "superclassOf": [
            {
              "_type": "Ubuntu",
              "superclassOf": [
                {
                  "_type": "Ubuntu1604",
                  "parameters": "JSON STRING"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `JSON STRING` is a dict in a string form (e.g. `'{"property1":"value1","property2":"value2"}'`).
What I am looking for is a way to navigate recoursively the `supeclassOf` property and convert these Json strings to real parts of json, and return the full dict once edited.

**EDIT**: note that `supeclassOf`'s values are lists. So everywhere there's a `superclassOf` there can be multiple elements, each having (or not) properties `parameters` and `superclassOf`

**EDIT2** using Prem Anand's answer I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/api/api.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/api/api.py", line 52, in main
    process_list_or_dict(library)
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/api/api.py", line 45, in process_list_or_dict
    process_list_or_dict(v)
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/api/api.py", line 45, in process_list_or_dict
    process_list_or_dict(v)
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/api/api.py", line 45, in process_list_or_dict
    process_list_or_dict(v)
  [Previous line repeated 5 more times]
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/api/api.py", line 43, in process_list_or_dict
    ld[k] = process_str(v)
  File "C:/Users/ceccolig/PycharmProjects/api/api.py", line 37, in process_str
    return json.loads(s)
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\ceccolig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? could you add some code you tried and didn't work ?

Comment: What do you mean by  **"convert these Json strings to real parts of json"** ?

Comment: @HichamZouarhi i don't know where to start really..

Comment: @MisterNox i mean that i can access those keys. In case of a string it cannot be done

Comment: well you can convert json data to lists/dicts so it is quite simple to access them, but give me a scenario. What should I do if I accessed them? Then I can give you an example

Comment: @MisterNox what i need is to edit recursively the entire dict. I don't know without reading where are the keys "properties" or which entry is superclassOf another

Comment: posted my answer right now, hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.loads` to convert the json string to dict. Navigate through each element of your dict, check if it is of type dict or list or string and process each type accordingly

```
import json

def process_str(s):
    if s and s[0]=='{' and s[-1]=='}':
        return json.loads(s)
    return s

def process_list_or_dict(ld):
    for k,v in enumerate(ld) if isinstance(ld, list) else ld.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            ld[k] = process_str(v)
        elif isinstance(v, (list, dict)):
            process_list_or_dict(v)
```

**Example**

```
dct = {'library': [{'_type': 'Host', 'parameters': '{"property1":"value1","property2":"value2"}', 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'LinuxHost', 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'Ubuntu', 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'Ubuntu1604', 'parameters': '{"property3":"value3","property4":"value4"}'}]}]}]}]}

process_list_or_dict(dct)

print(json.dumps(dct, indent=4))
```

**Output**

```
{
    "library": [
        {
            "_type": "Host",
            "parameters": {
                "property1": "value1",
                "property2": "value2"
            },
            "superclassOf": [
                {
                    "_type": "LinuxHost",
                    "superclassOf": [
                        {
                            "_type": "Ubuntu",
                            "superclassOf": [
                                {
                                    "_type": "Ubuntu1604",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "property3": "value3",
                                        "property4": "value4"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get an error. Check my question edit

Comment: check EDIT2 in my question

Comment: Your error means that the JSON_STRING you are using is not a valid json string. Are the individual words wrapped in double quotes as in the example string `'{"property1":"value1","property2":"value2"}'`

Comment: Yes I was missing a wrong string. But now it gives me this: `if s[0]=='{' and s[-1]=='}': IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: Just updated my answer to replace `if s[0]=='{' and s[-1]=='}':` with `if s and s[0]=='{' and s[-1]=='}':`. That should fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218828/discussion-between-cristina-and-prem-anand).

Comment: The error shows when the function parses a key whose value is  '' (double sigle quote) but check s!='' doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Okay now I got you I hope. [With reference to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713877/recursively-iterate-through-a-nested-dict-with-list-and-replace-matched-values), I modified the answer so that it should work for you. Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
import json

data = {
  "library": [
    {
      "_type": "Host",
      "parameters": '{"property1":"value1","property2":"value2"}',
      "superclassOf": [
        {
          "_type": "LinuxHost",
          "superclassOf": [
            {
              "_type": "Ubuntu",
              "superclassOf": [
                {
                  "_type": "Ubuntu1604",
                  "parameters": '{"property1":"value1","property2":"value2"}'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


# if you want to modify a specific key's value where you only know the key
def replace(data, key_match, repl):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {k: replace((v if k != key_match else repl), key_match, repl) for k, v in data.items()}
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        return [replace(i, key_match, repl) for i in data]
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        try:
            data = json.loads(data)
            return replace(data, key_match, repl)
        except ValueError:
            return data
    else:
        return data

print(replace(data, "property1", "Modified"))
# {'library': [{'_type': 'Host', 'parameters': {'property1': 'Modified', 'property2': 'value2'}, 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'LinuxHost', 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'Ubuntu', 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'Ubuntu1604', 'parameters': {'property1': 'Modified', 'property2': 'value2'}}]}]}]}]}
```

**EDIT**

If you only want to convert the json.

```
def convertJSON(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {k: convertJSON(v) for k, v in data.items()}
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        return [convertJSON(i) for i in data]
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        try:
            data = json.loads(data)
            return convertJSON(data)
        except ValueError:
            return data
    else:
        return data

print(convertJSON(data))
# {'library': [{'_type': 'Host', 'parameters': {'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'}, 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'LinuxHost', 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'Ubuntu', 'superclassOf': [{'_type': 'Ubuntu1604', 'parameters': {'property1': 'value1', 'property2': 'value2'}}]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to replace keys' values. I just want to use json.loads where there's a string that reminds a json structure

Comment: Then you only need to modify the replace method. I added modified method in my answer